# Mounted directory using rclone is read-only

Tags: root-access, mount, cifs

I am on a rooted Android 12 device (Orange Pi 5 Plus) and I have managed to setup and mount a samba share to a local directory using the following commands:

```
su
export PATH="/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin:$PATH"
rclone mount rpi4:/raspberrypidocker/shared /data/media/0/rpi4 --allow-other --config="/sdcard/.rclone/rclone.conf"
```

This works and it looks like all apps are able to read the contents of that directory. The problem is that no app can write to this directory. I receive:

```
/storage/emulated/0: read-only filesystem
```

However I am able to write to that directory before I mount it with rclone.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: On older devices the access control to `/storage/emulated/0` was performed by a Linux group for read and/or write permissions. Not sure if this measure still exists on Android 12. What file permission have you set to the mount point and what user/group are displayed in `ls -l` for the files in the share?

Comment: I have tried mounting with --dir-perms 0777 --file-perms 0777 --umask=0 but there was no difference. The ls -l command shows root everybody 0 for all the files and directories inside. Note that I am not using the /storage/emulated/0 mountpoint because it wasn't visible to other apps so I had to use the media one.